# Skip and take options not working with include

Tags: next.js, prisma

```js
const inventory = await prisma.inventory.findMany({
  skip: (page - 1) * limit,
  take: JSON.parse(limit),
  include: {
    warehouses_stock: true,
  },
});

return NextResponse.json(inventory);
```

The pagination is working fine but the warehouses_stock returns an empty array.

I removed the skip and take options and it seems to be returning the warehouses_stock as it should.

Comment: In one of those you're multiplying by `limit`, with the other you're json parsing `limit`. What type is `limit`? Technically it works `234 * "2" === 468` and `JSON.parse("2") === 2`, but that might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Store the logic in a variable:

```js
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
```

Then use it like this:

```js
  const page = parseInt(req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("page"));
  const limit = parseInt(req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("limit"));
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

    const inventory = await prisma.inventory.findMany({
      skip: skip,
      take: limit,
      include: {
        warehouses_stock: true,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(inventory);
```